# how to limit the number of textboxes to be added (php)

Tags: javascript, php

the following codes offers infinite number of input boxes to  be added. What i want is to limit the number of textboxes to be added. It should only be up to 3.

```html
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])){
    print_r($_POST);
}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("#button_add_input").click(function(event){
                var textArea = "<textarea name='new_quote[]' />";
                $("#div_quotes").append(textArea);
                $("#div_quotes").append("\n<br />");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
<div id="div_quotes"></div>
<input type="button" value="Add Text Area" id="button_add_input">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add counter and check it value is less than 3

Answer (score 0):

You can just use JQuery [descendant selector](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) to count the number (using [`.length`](https://api.jquery.com/length/)) of textareas in your div.

```html
<?php if (isset($_POST[ 'submitted'])){ print_r($_POST); } ?>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $("#button_add_input").click(function(event) {
        if ($("#div_quotes textarea").length < 3) {
          var textArea = "<textarea name='new_quote[]' />";
          $("#div_quotes").append(textArea);
          $("#div_quotes").append("\n<br />");
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="post">
    <div id="div_quotes"></div>
    <input type="button" value="Add Text Area" id="button_add_input">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```